# EF Generate database from code issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Let me try to explain this.

I started a new project (MVC5) and I created a database with 2 tables (from the EF Video examples) Blogs and Posts.
I created the relationship in the database, and then I downloaded the EF tools from VistualStudioGallery.com

I then used the tool to reverse engineer the tables to generate the context and model classes/mappings.

So far so good.

Then I modified the db context to look like this:

```
public partial class EfExampleContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public EfExampleContext()
        : base("Name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BlogMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PostMap());
    }
}
```

Then I deleted the database and F5 ran my project in the hope it would generate my database, which it did.
I noticed that it generated the **Posts**, **Blogs**, **AspNetUsers**, **AspNetUserRoles**, **AspNetRoles**, **AspNetUserClaims** and **AspNetUserLogins** tables with the correct columns and relationships.

I then deleted the database and the **AspNetUser** models.
I then removed references to:

1. EntityFramework
2. Microsoft Asp.net Identity Core
3. Microsoft Asp.net Identity EntityFramework
4. Microsoft Asp.net Identity Owin

and then installed them with the latest versions. I did this because I want to work with **IdentityUser** and not **AspNetUser** (There are some differences).

I then F5 ran my project to create my database and this is where the problems started...

**IdentityUser** looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Note the ICollection navigation property**.
The **IdentityUserLogin** model looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUserLogin
{
    public IdentityUserLogin();

    public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the IdentityUser can have **multiple** Logins and the Login has **one** User. If I run that project the **IdentityUserLogins** table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentityUserLogins](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [User_Id] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.IdentityUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

There is something wrong here. UserId is a PK so it can not be a 0 to many relationship with **IdentityUsers** which is why EF is adding the other **User_Id** column but that makes no sense.

My question is, has anyone come across this before?
If so, how do I generate the correct mapping to fix it?

Please note that **obviously** I cannot change the **IdentityUser** class to make **ICollection** a single reference (i.e. not a collection)

/r3plica

Answer (score 0):

because of Convention

```
public class IdentityUserLogin
{

 public IdentityUserLogin();

public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
public virtual string UserId { get; set; }  // if i am the key to IdentityUser

 [ForeignKey("UserId")] //  IdentityUserId instead of USerId may have worked.
                        //  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564 and  
                        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583
public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
```

}

EDIT2 Fluent API  .. change as required for 1:1/!:M/M:M, required/optional etc

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasRequired(t=>t.IdentityUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.UserId)
```

[fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to map that using the fluent api because I don't have access to the IdentityUserLogin class or can I override the propery to add the constraint?

Comment: When I add that, I get the following error: dentityUserLogin_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'IdentityUserLogin_User_Source' in relationship 'IdentityUserLogin_User'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.